# Can a C program that uses SDL2 run in a bare metal environment (no Operating system)?

Tags: c, embedded, sdl, bare-metal

So I'm trying to design a program that takes a JSON file, parses it, and then creates a display on a touchscreen. So far I've written a program that does pretty much just that using Visual Studio, cJSON, and SDL2. However, the program is meant to be run on a bare metal STM microcontroller evaluation board. Is anything in the SDL library that is dependent on Windows or will the program run the same in a bare metal environment?

Comment: SDL: simple directmedia layer. Depends heavily on the underlying system. If there's no system, you're toast. unless there's a SDL lib for your microcontroller (there's one for the Nintendo DS after all)

Comment: what are you using sdl to do?  My limited experience with SDL was a baremetal like feel, so replace the sdl with baremetal.  dont try to port it.

Comment: ascii files generally dont make sense and you probably want to avoid json as well, maybe have a program on the host convert the json into something more efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SDL exists in many platforms (Windows, Linux, AmigaOS & Nintendo DS, BeOS, Android, and probably others)

But it relies on the operating system / hardware features to create display & sounds, and get input.

If your microcontroller has no OS, SDL cannot be ported to it easily. So either you find a specific version of SDL on your platform or you'll have to port it yourself, which doesn't seem to be a piece of cake. Besides you probably need 5% of SDL features so why bother?

The other solution would be to write your app without SDL, using the bare metal video/input capabilities of your microcontroller. It doesn't need to be portable, and you'll save time trying to port an abstract layer for your system for a simple app.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'm a bit new to this whole embedded programming world so the simple explanation is greatly appreciated. I'm going to use one of the STM embedded graphics libraries once my parts actually arrive along with the parsing portion of the code I wrote. For the time being though I am going to use SDL to prototype and debug my parsing code/ JSON file.

Comment: yes, you can even specify a simpler interface which calls either the embedded libs or SDL depending on the platform.